# Using a text file to create a dataframe with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to use a text file to create a database in which I can easily search through with specific values such as "items with roi>50%" or "items with monthly sales >50"

I got as far as reading the file in and creating a list that was split after each 'New Flip!' which indexed each entry into the list but I don't know how to best name each of the attributes of each object within the list so they can be called upon.

I also tried creating a pd dataframe with each item being the rows and each column being the attributes but once again I was able to create the individual rows that contained the entire contents of each index but don't know how to split up each attribute of each item.

The text file output is set up as:

```
Donquixote
`New Flip!`
__**Product Details**__
> **Name:** Star Wars
> **ASIN:** B0
__**Analytics**__
> **Rank:** 79,371/7,911,836 (Top 1.00%) **Toys & Games**
> **Monthly Sales:** 150
> **Offer Count #:** 8
__**Calculation**__
> **Sell:** $49.99
> **Buy:** $20.99
> **FBA Fees:** $7.50
> **Pick and Pack Fees:** $3.64
> **Ship to Amazon:** $0.53
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━
> **Profit:** $17.34
> **ROI:** 82%
__**Links**__
> **[Check Restriction](https://sellercentr)**
> **[Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B)**
> **[Keepa](https://keepa.com/#!product/1-B)**
> **[Bestbuy](https://www.bestbuy.com/si**
https://images-ext-1.discorda
https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/extern
A︱01/03/22
{Reactions}
 keepa barcode   
[02-Jan-22 11:23 PM] 
{Embed}
Donquixote
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why does the file look like this? Why not create a file designed to be used by Pandas' built-in tools for reading Dataframes from file? Also, for the data that you show, what should the corresponding Dataframe contain? How many columns should it have, what should the column labels be, and which pieces of information go in what columns? What other processing needs to be done? Please read [ask] and [mre], and also keep in mind that this is not a code-writing service - you should show your existing attempt, and ask a *specific* question related to the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that your text document is item after item all in the same document (I have added "Batman" as an additional item so that you can see how the code works).

```
Donquixote
`New Flip!`
__**Product Details**__
> **Name:** Star Wars
> **ASIN:** B0
__**Analytics**__
> **Rank:** 79,371/7,911,836 (Top 1.00%) **Toys & Games**
> **Monthly Sales:** 150
> **Offer Count #:** 8
__**Calculation**__
> **Sell:** $49.99
> **Buy:** $20.99
> **FBA Fees:** $7.50
> **Pick and Pack Fees:** $3.64
> **Ship to Amazon:** $0.53
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━
> **Profit:** $17.34
> **ROI:** 82%
__**Links**__
> **[Check Restriction](https://sellercentr)**
> **[Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B)**
> **[Keepa](https://keepa.com/#!product/1-B)**
> **[Bestbuy](https://www.bestbuy.com/si**
https://images-ext-1.discorda
https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/extern
A︱01/03/22
{Reactions}
 keepa barcode   
[02-Jan-22 11:23 PM] 
{Embed}
Donquixote
`New Flip!`
__**Product Details**__
> **Name:** Batman
> **ASIN:** B1
__**Analytics**__
> **Rank:** 79,371/7,911,836 (Top 1.00%) **Toys & Games**
> **Monthly Sales:** 20
> **Offer Count #:** 8
__**Calculation**__
> **Sell:** $45.99
> **Buy:** $20.99
> **FBA Fees:** $7.50
> **Pick and Pack Fees:** $3.64
> **Ship to Amazon:** $0.53
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━
> **Profit:** $17.34
> **ROI:** 56%
__**Links**__
> **[Check Restriction](https://sellercentr)**
> **[Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B)**
> **[Keepa](https://keepa.com/#!product/1-B)**
> **[Bestbuy](https://www.bestbuy.com/si**
https://images-ext-1.discorda
https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/extern
A︱01/03/22
{Reactions}
 keepa barcode   
[02-Jan-22 11:23 PM] 
{Embed}
```

This, messy and rudimentary, code could then be used:

```
database = {}
data = {}
name = ""

# open file
with open("data.txt", "rt", encoding="utf8") as file:
    for line in file:
        # if "New Flip!" then new item
        if "New Flip!" in line:
            for x in data.keys():
                # convert money values to floats
                if "$" in data[x]:
                    data[x] = float(data[x].strip("$"))
                # convert other numbers to floats
                elif data[x].isdigit():
                    data[x] = float(data[x])
                # convert ROI to float
                if x == "ROI:":
                    data[x] = float(data[x].strip("%"))
            # add item's data to the database
            database[name] = data
            # start a new item
            data = {}
        try:
            # if a name, define "name" as this value to name the data correctly
            if line.split("**")[1] == "Name:":
                name = line.split("**")[2].strip()
            # dictionary key names are after the first "**", and values after the second
            data[line.split("**")[1]] = line.split("**")[2].strip()
        except:
            pass

import pandas as pd
# convert database to dataframe and transpose so each row is an item and each column a dictionary key
df = pd.DataFrame(database).T
# filter for items with ROI > 60
df[df["ROI:"] > 60]
#          Product Details      Name: ASIN: Analytics                         Rank: Monthly Sales: Offer Count #: Calculation  Sell:   Buy: FBA Fees: Pick and Pack Fees: Ship to Amazon: Profit:  ROI: Links [Check Restriction](https://sellercentr) [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B) [Keepa](https://keepa.com/#!product/1-B) [Bestbuy](https://www.bestbuy.com/si
#Star Wars              __  Star Wars    B0        __  79,371/7,911,836 (Top 1.00%)          150.0            8.0          __  49.99  20.99       7.5                3.64            0.53   17.34  82.0    __
```

Notice that Batman, which has ROI of 56%, is not included in the filtered dataframe.